# How to find all the courses that a user has joined? Mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am struggling to find the courses that a user has joined.
I have this course model schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const CourseSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    code:{
        type:String,
    },
    joined:[
        {
            user:{
                type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
                ref:'user'
            }
        }
    ]
})

module.exports = Course = mongoose.model('course',CourseSchema);
```

The user schema is

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

I have the id of the user, how to find the courses that a user has joined?

Comment: Have you tried using $elemMatch on the joined array to fetch by user Id?

Comment: David you are asking questions but not accepting answers or commenting whether if they are worked or not, this is not good. I was about to answer your question, but just noticed that you didn't say anything or do something in your this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58703082/how-to-get-the-names-from-the-ids-in-mongoose

Comment: I am sorry SuleymanSah I thought I replied to your answer

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't have any reference from User model to Course model, you need to use virtual populate.

User model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true
  }
},
  {
    toJSON: { virtuals: true },
    toObject: { virtuals: true }
  });

// Virtual populate
UserSchema.virtual('courses', {
  ref: 'course',
  foreignField: 'joined.user',
  localField: '_id'
});

module.exports = User = mongoose.model("user", UserSchema);
```

After this you can use a route like this to populate a given user's courses:

```
router.get("/user/:id/courses", async (req, res) => {

  try {

    let userCourses = await User.findById(req.params.id).populate({ path: "courses" });

    res.status(200).send(userCourses);

  } catch (err) {
    console.log(err);
    res.status(500).send(err);
  }
});
```

The result will be something like this:

```
{
    "_id": "5dc84862b1f1bd0b2035813a",
    "name": "User 1 name",
    "email": "user1@gmail.com",
    "__v": 0,
    "courses": [
        {
            "_id": "5dc848f2b1f1bd0b2035813e",
            "code": "Course 1 code",
            "joined": [
                {
                    "_id": "5dc848f2b1f1bd0b20358141",
                    "user": "5dc84862b1f1bd0b2035813a"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc848f2b1f1bd0b20358140",
                    "user": "5dc84876b1f1bd0b2035813b"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc848f2b1f1bd0b2035813f",
                    "user": "5dc8487fb1f1bd0b2035813c"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dc84911b1f1bd0b20358142",
            "code": "Course 2 code",
            "joined": [
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84911b1f1bd0b20358144",
                    "user": "5dc84862b1f1bd0b2035813a"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84911b1f1bd0b20358143",
                    "user": "5dc84876b1f1bd0b2035813b"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        },
        {
            "_id": "5dc84969b1f1bd0b20358145",
            "code": "Course 3 code",
            "joined": [
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84969b1f1bd0b20358149",
                    "user": "5dc84862b1f1bd0b2035813a"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84969b1f1bd0b20358148",
                    "user": "5dc84876b1f1bd0b2035813b"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84969b1f1bd0b20358147",
                    "user": "5dc8487fb1f1bd0b2035813c"
                },
                {
                    "_id": "5dc84969b1f1bd0b20358146",
                    "user": "5dc84888b1f1bd0b2035813d"
                }
            ],
            "__v": 0
        }
    ],
    "id": "5dc84862b1f1bd0b2035813a"
}
```

Virtual populate docs:

https://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html#populate-virtuals

Comment: Is not there any neater way to do it? Like looping through all courses, then for each course to loop if there exists a user in joined array?

Comment: @DavidConway this is the best way, looping will be slow. Why don't you like this way? Did you try it?

Comment: I do not think that looping will be slow O(nlog(n)). I am used with SQL and for me in SQL it is very easy to do this. Thus, for a simple query I am making changes in my schema which in my opinion is not neat. Thank you though!

Comment: Making  small changes in schema is not a problem. I assure you that this is the best option. Looping is very amateurish. But you know.

Comment: By the way, I just want to get the name of the courses, this returns far more things than it's necessary.

Comment: @DavidConway you don't want the user info?

Comment: If you only want user name, you can try like this: await User.findById(req.params.id).select("name").populate({ path: "courses" });

Comment: @DavidConway virtual fields maybe not cannot excluded, but you can remove them in your router.

Comment: Course.find({"joined.user":req.user.id}) , it was as simple as that.

Comment: @DavidConway yes that seems also an option, if you don't want any info from user. But I still think my solution is still useful.